# How to configure route path to direct controller instead of getting method name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

[Code img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql9JW.png)

[Config img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2taj.png)

This is a C# ASP.NET Web API program running on .NET 4.8.1.

I've tried leaving out the `ActionName`, and I've tried a method called `Get()`, but it doesn't work.

I would like to access it directly through something like

```
get api/user?userCode=
```

Route config:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Controller:

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, ActionName("Get")]
    public object GetUserInfo(string userCode)
    {
        return new { userCode, userPwd = "123" };
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question. Images of code are not code that we can debug, or help you with.

Comment: ok @ProgrammingLlama, thanks for the advice.  I've update and provide the c# code.

Comment: First of all, leaving out `ActionName`, the URL would be `/api/user/getuserinfo`. And also: the route config defines a parameter `id` - your method however expects `userCode`. Try to call the method parameter `id` - does it work then?

Comment: if i leaving out ActionName, then call `api/User/GetUserInfo?userCode=23` will working. but I would like to define the call path like this `api/user?userCode=`, The other controllers just use the default configuration routes. @marc_s

Comment: Not sure if setting `ActionName("")` would accomplish this .... the route **dictates** that there must be a `{action}` after the controller name - not sure if you can omit that

Comment: If `ActionName("")` is set, an exception is thrown： "The route template separator character '/' cannot appear consecutively. It must be separated by either a parameter or a literal value"

Comment: Hello, I am a newbie. Very short of reputation right now.
I often see helpful answers that I can't click on `useful`, and it bothers me!
If you think my answer is okay, can you give my answer a `USEFUL`, thanks @marc_s

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I searched for this solution. By saying use the Route attribute, you can customize routes for a single Controller. The prerequisite is to enable a configuration

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

```
[RoutePrefix("api/user")]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public object GetUserInfo(string userCode)
    {
        return new { userCode, userPwd = "123" };
    }
}
```

[Successful ScreenShot Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9iqR.png)